# How to do outer join on two columns in Pig Latin

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I do outer joins on single columns in Pig like this

```
result = JOIN A by id LEFT OUTER, B by id;
```

How do I join on two columns, something like -

```
WHERE A.id=B.id AND A.name=B.name
```

What is the pig equivalent?  I couldn't find any example in the pig manuals...any help?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Answering the question myself -

```
join a by (id, name), b by (id, name)
```

http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449302641/advanced_pig_latin.html

Comment: You forgot LEFT OUTER

Answer (score 40):

The above answer is actually an INNER join, the correct pig statement should be:

```
 join a by (id, name) LEFT OUTER, b by (id, name)
```